# If package is not loaded, provide command that doesn't interfere

Tags: macros, nesting

In a ([complicated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325871/4736)) definition of a command, I'm using `\hyperref{...`. But the package hyperref slows down compilation. So I'd like to make `\hyperref`simply do nothing, as long as the package hyperref is not loaded.

In a later stage I'd like to add `\usepackage{hyperref}`to my text, when I have to compile less often.

So I thought of `\providecommand`. What I don't know, is how to define `\hyperref` in a way that it simply does nothing, *but without preventing the rest of my complicated command from being executed.*

I wrote a MWE. In case the `hyperref` package is not loaded, `\secref`should be executed as if there were no `\hyperref`, which means in the case of my stupid example, just `\ref`should be executed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\hyperref}{»DO NOTHING«}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \hyperref{%
    \ref{#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Huhu}
\label{CLA:huhu}

Text \secref{CLA:huhu}

\end{document}
```

I know that my example won't work, *if* I load the `hyperref` package, but this isn't the question. I lacked of a better idea for the MWE.

Comment: I don't get this really. You want replace `\hyperref` to fall back to `\ref`?

Comment: No, I want `\hyperref`to do nothing, as long as the package hyperref is not loaded. But 'nothing' means, the rest of the command `\secref`should be executed.

Comment: Why don't you do simply `\providecommand{\hyperref}{}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I'm clueless?!

Comment: `\hyperref` either has an optional argument and a mandatory one or another version with 4 mand. arguments, none of them is gobbled away with `\providecommand{hyperref}{}` in my point of view!

Comment: @KeksDose: You have a spurious space in your definition of `\secref`. If you remove this space, then `\providecommand{\hyperref}[2][]{#2}` should do what you ask.

Comment: @Werner What is the difference to Ulrike's idea `\providecommand{\hyperref}{}`?

Comment: @KeksDose: Mine includes the possibility that you specified an optional argument with \hyperref[.]{..}.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `hyperref` bundle comes with the `nohyperref` package, which provides the command syntax of `hyperref` without the actual complicated `hyperref` mechanism. This makes it useful for draft documents, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nohyperref}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{section \ref*{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Huhu}
\label{CLA:huhu}

Text \secref{CLA:huhu}

\end{document}
```

When you're approaching the final version of the document, you just need to replace `nohyperref` with `hyperref`.

Another possibility is to load `hyperref` with the `draft` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{section \ref*{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Huhu}
\label{CLA:huhu}

Text \secref{CLA:huhu}

\end{document}
```

This also speeds up document compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use `\ignorespaces`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\hyperref}[4]{#1\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \hyperref{%
    \ref{#1}
  }{}{}{}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Huhu}
\label{CLA:huhu}

Text \secref{CLA:huhu}


\end{document}
```