# How to cross-reference a third-level sectioning header while including the higher-level sectioning numbers

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, nameref

My document structure looks like this:

```
I. Example-heading
  1. Example-subheading
  2. Example-subheading 2
    a) Example-subsubheading
    b) Example-subsubheading 2
       (aa) Example-subsubsubheading
       (bb) Example-subsubheading 2
          ...
             ...
               ...
II. Example-heading 2
  1. Example2-subheading
```

When I now use

```
\subthreesection{Example-subsubsubheading}\label{my-label}
```

and later on somewhere in the text

```
\ref{my-label} \nameref{my-label}
```

The output is like

> **(aa) Example-subsubsubheading**

But I would like to have

> **I.2.a).(aa) Example-subsubsubheading**

And not only for third-level but for seven-level or deeper.

I'm using the document class [hausarbeit-jura](https://github.com/sieversMartin/hausarbeit-jura) (a document class for jura student papers).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Also, do tell us how you've changed the numbering style of `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`-level headers.

Comment: I added the name of the document class - hausarbeit-jura. But I don't know how it changes the numbering style.

Comment: @Yeti: Unfortunately this document class changes the numbering really and there is no easy way to track `b)` back to the first chapter and another `b)` back to another chapter etc.

Comment: Thanks for indicating which document class you use. I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your posting to streamline the exposition.

Comment: Thanks for updating the title! But to be exact it is not only referncing third-level but also seven- or n-level sections.

Comment: @Yeti - It's always a good idea -- at least on this site -- to state up front fully and clearly what the objective is. If some things are left unsaid, the likelihood that they'll somehow get divined and acted on anyway is rather low...

Comment: @Mico I was not aware, that my question suggested third level-referencing. Thanks everyone for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use the `hausarbeit-jura` document class, I suggest you modify the "prefix macros" `\p@subsection`, `\p@subsubsection`, and `\p@subthreesection`. Specifically, you should insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection}
\renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\p@subsection\thesubsection}
\renewcommand\p@subthreesection{\p@subsubsection\thesubsubsection.}
\renewcommand\p@subfoursection{\p@subthreesection\thesubthreesection.}
\renewcommand\p@subfivesection{\p@subfoursection\thesubfoursection.}
\renewcommand\p@subsixsection{\p@subfivesection\thesubfivesection.}
\makeatother
```

*Remark*: I've added three additional levels of cross-referencing prefix macros beyond those you requested in your initial posting. I trust you have enough information to carry on to levels seven and eight as well as to paragraph and subparagraphs...

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{hausarbeit-jura}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % for \nameref macro

\makeatletter  % use a recursive approach to define the prefix macros:
\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection}
\renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\p@subsection\thesubsection}
\renewcommand\p@subthreesection{\p@subsubsection\thesubsubsection.}
\renewcommand\p@subfoursection{\p@subthreesection\thesubthreesection.}
\renewcommand\p@subfivesection{\p@subfoursection\thesubfoursection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
level-1 sub: \ref{my-label1} \nameref{my-label1}

level-2 sub: \ref{my-label2} \nameref{my-label2}

level-3 sub: \ref{my-label3} \nameref{my-label3}

level-4 sub: \ref{my-label4} \nameref{my-label4}

level-5 sub: \ref{my-label5} \nameref{my-label5}

etc.

\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Subsection heading} \label{my-label1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection heading} \label{my-label2}
\subthreesection{Subthree-heading} \label{my-label3}
\subfoursection{Subfour-heading} \label{my-label4}
\subfivesection{Subfive-heading} \label{my-label5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. I considered this also ...(+1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I sad above I was not that exact in the original question as i thought. It is not about referencing only third-level sections but also like seven- or n-level section ...

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the  numbering style (which must be setup differently and that's a **different** question) the 'contraction' of the reference style can be achieved easily with `zref` when links are required, just replace `\label` with `zlabel` and setup a `\fullref` command that extracts the anchor, default value and title of the link.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[user,hyperref,titleref]{zref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{%
  % Check for existence and provide a hyperlink
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{default} \zref@extract{#1}{title}}%
  }%    
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

See \fullref{my-label}

\chapter{Example-heading}
\section{Example-subheading}
\section{Example-subheading 2}
\subsection{Example subsubheading} 

\subsubsection{Example subsubheading} 
\subsubsection{Example subsubheading 2}  \zlabel{my-label}

\chapter{Example-heading 2}
\section{Example-subheading again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update for the `hausarbeit-jura.cls`**

```
\documentclass{hausarbeit-jura}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[counter,user,hyperref,titleref]{zref}


\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapterprop}{\thechapter}
\zref@newprop{sectionprop}{\thesection}
\zref@newprop{subsectionprop}{\thesubsection}
\zref@newprop{subsubsectionprop}{\thesubsubsection}
\zref@addprops{main}{chapterprop,sectionprop,subsectionprop,subsubsectionprop}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \extractstructure #1{
  \str_case_x:nn {\zref@extract{#1}{counter} }
  {
    {chapter} {\zref@extract{#1}{chapterprop} }
    {section} {\zref@extract{#1}{chapterprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{sectionprop} }
    {subsection} {\zref@extract{#1}{chapterprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{sectionprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{subsectionprop} }
    {subsubsection} {\zref@extract{#1}{chapterprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{sectionprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{subsectionprop}~\zref@extract{#1}{subsubsectionprop} }
  } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{%
  % Check for existence and provide a hyperlink
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\extractstructure{#1} \zref@extract{#1}{title}}
  }%    
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

See \fullref{my-label} or \fullref{somechapter}

\chapter{Example-heading}
\section{Example-subheading}
\section{Example-subheading 2}
\subsection{Example subsubheading} 

\subsubsection{Example subsubheading} 
\subsubsection{Example subsubheading 2}  \zlabel{my-label}

\chapter{Example-heading 2} \zlabel{somechapter}
\section{Example-subheading again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is working without `\chapter` but with `\subthreesection`. [Aside: The OP's document class also provides `\subfoursection`, ... , `\subeightsection` macros. Downright scary, if you ask me.]

Comment: @Mico: I will change later on... and yes, what has jurisdiction ever done for us, apart from strange numbering/structuring schemes ;-)

Comment: I suppose each profession has managed to develop its own set of barriers to entry to keep all but the most dedicated wannabes out. In some fields the barrier is an ability to do math comfortably and competently -- this includes my field (economics  -- Volkswirtschaftslehre. In other fields it's an expectation to read lots and lots of books and pamphlets, many of which are of dubious to low intrinsic interest and value (literature...). In law, it's quite evidently an ability to build and keep track of rather elaborate numbering systems...

Comment: @Mico You're right about the chapters. I only use section down to subsevensection (and could(!) use than up to subparagraph). And you are right about the barriers. :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question with a standard document class: [Abbreviated references: just the necessary references, no more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314279/abbreviated-references-just-the-necessary-references-no-more)

In a nutshell: If I'm on the "II." branch, the reference from e.g. II.3.b) doesn't need to be to II.1.a), but simply 1.a). But if I'm refering from somewhere under III., the reference in the text has to bee II.1.a), of course.

It took me a whole day and much help to find this solution:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325871/4736