# Change cross-reference format if referencing elsewhere in the same chapter

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I have a multi-part project where I'm using a custom format for subsubsection cross-references:

```
\labelformat{subsubsection}{Pt~\arabic{part}, Ch~\thechapter, Sec~\thesubsubsection}
```

> Pt 1, Ch 2, Sec 3.4.5

This displays the Part, Chapter, and subsubsection numbers, and is fine for when referencing between different chapters.

When referencing something elsewhere within the same chapter, I would like to drop the Part and Chapter numbers, so it instead appears as:

```
\labelformat{subsubsection}{Sec~\thesubsubsection}
```

> Sec 3.4.5

Is this possible while still keeping the original behaviour for references between different chapters? Many thanks.

Comment: well I told you in your previous question that it isn't a great idea to put everything in the label. See here for some idea how to build a more complex reference system https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325319/2388

Comment: Thanks - I agree, I'm just restricted in format by the particular use case I'm working in. I'm finding the examples/documentation for \zref a little heavy, but I'll keep experimenting with it.